# Error by analyzing the module in Tessy (symbol multiply defined in *.o file)

Tags: c, unit-testing

I am testing C code in Tessy.
By analyzing the module I get the following error that is shown in the picture.

[image]

Due to the fact that in documentation I couldn't find anything that would help me in solving the problem, I'm asking for your help.
Maybe someone recognizes the problem and can give me a feedback.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the c code?

Comment: Sounds like `___ghsend_stack` is defined multiple times in the file pointed to. Without the code in that file I don't think anyone can help you further.